# A bat file runs properly in Common fileFolder, but flash pass at system folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, flash

## At first,this is my bat code:

```
@echo off
    echo 此程序是用于，在每次启动Win7时，自动更换Win7的登录背景。它的登录背景的切换，
    echo 是基于一组图片进行轮播
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo 程序思路：Win7文件夹下名字为backgroundDefault.jpg的图片会被当作登录背景图片显示。
    echo 程序的主要作用，是在那一组图片中，适当的修改每个图片的名称，
    echo 从而实现每次开机的登录界面都不相同
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    rem 程序开始 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem 先将最小序号的L（min），改为backgroundDefault.jpg

rem 前提是不能存在同名的改后的文件的结果，因此

ren "backgroundDefault.jpg" "backgroundDefault"

ren "L1.jpg" "backgroundDefault.jpg"

rem 声明一个变量，获取当前L之后的序号
rem set picName=this is

rem pause

rem 统计L开头的文件的个数（应当多个1出来）
set /a sum=1

rem 循环求和 L开头的文件的数量

for %%x in (L*.jpg) do (
set picName=%%x
rem echo !picName!

rem pause

set next=!picName:~1,1!
set /a next=next-1
rem echo !next!
rem pause

rem 重命名文件
ren !picName! "L"!next!".jpg"

rem echo L!next!.jpg
rem pause

set /a sum=sum+1
)

rem 最后将backgroundDefault，改为backgroundDefault.jpg

ren "backgroundDefault" "L"!sum!".jpg"

rem pause
```

- I use it to change my Win7 login interface picture auto,
- I spend half of a day to write it,And it runs properly in my test folder,
- when I copy my pictures and bat files to the folder of

  > - "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds",
- just click the bat file,and it turn out to be flash pass.
- I have tried modify the authority of it, but it not works.
- I really want to know why, I'm so appreciate for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing permissions or running it as an Admin.

Comment: I was tried as you say , but it till the flash pass. and ,the point is the tick square is grey at its properties of runing as an Admin. I think you can try my script, and maybe you'll find the question as I was met.

Comment: You said right, When I use my Inner administrator account to log on，it works, but how to made my self account the inner administrator, It seems can't.